# python import No module named 'api'

Tags: python

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyLY2.png)
In the code with the above configuration, main.py imports ChzzkRun.py and then imports ChzzkRun.py
ChzzkRun.py imports api.py

However, when running on ChzzkRun.py , it works, but when the main fetches and run it with from ChzzkChatLog.ChzzkRun import ChzzkChat, the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api' occurs.

I don't know how it works even after thinking about it for a long time, so I write a question.

tried import api.py but same problem

Comment: All imports within a package MUST use relative imports

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `import ChzzkChatlog.api`?  ChzzkRun.py should be able to find it easily since it is in the same package however for main.py is not, it has to look into ChzzkChatlog package. Basically what the comment showed.

Comment: I tried everything but didn't work. Lastly, I changed the file name and it was solved